# SQLite -- joining two subqueries

Tags: join, sqlite, subquery

Or at least I think they're called subqueries (newbie and self-trained in SQLite). I have two `SELECT` statements from two tables in the same database. I would like to join these two subqueries along the columns `date` and `symbol`. The subqueries work fine separately, but when I try to `JOIN` I get an error (`error in statement: near "JOIN": syntax error`). Here's my query string:

```
SELECT date, symbol, SUM(oi*contract_settle) AS oi_dollar
    FROM (SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
            FROM ann
            UNION
            SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
            FROM qtr) 
    GROUP BY date, symbol
    HAVING oi_dollar > 0
    JOIN
    (SELECT date, symbol, ret FROM crsp
    USING (date, symbol))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your JOIN clause needs to be before the GROUP BY clause.  Also, I know sqlite does has a few different "optional" syntaxes for joins, but the following more standard query should work:

```
SELECT a.date, a.symbol, SUM(a.oi * a.contract_settle) AS oi_dollar
FROM (SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
        FROM ann
        UNION
        SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
        FROM qtr) a
INNER JOIN crsp c ON a.date = c.date AND a.symbol = c.symbol
WHERE a.oi * a.contract_settle > 0
GROUP BY a.date, a.symbol
```

If you know slightly more about the oi and contract_settle columns (like, that they can never both be negative), a WHERE clause of `a.oi <> 0 AND a.contract_settle <> 0` might have better performance.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I want to ignore rows w/ zero `oi` or zero `contract settle`, and both must be non-negative, so I used `HAVING oi_dollar > 0` at the end of the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to define how you are joining by an on clause.  I don't know about SQLite, but in SQL, it would be like this (may not run):

```
SELECT date, symbol, SUM(oi*contract_settle) AS oi_dollar
    FROM (SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
            FROM ann
            UNION
            SELECT date, symbol, oi, contract_settle
            FROM qtr) as 'a'
    JOIN
    (SELECT date, symbol, ret FROM crsp
    USING (date, symbol)) as 'b'
    ON a.date = b.date AND a.symbol = b.symbol
    GROUP BY date, symbol
    HAVING oi_dollar > 0
```